# c++ How do you call a templated base-class function from derived class instance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Found related questions but not the exact variant so I am posting a very simple question. 
A derived class inherits from a templated base, and I want to call the base function, how to do it?

```
template <class A>
class testBase {
public:
    void insert(const A& insertType) {
         // whatever
    }
};

class testDerived : testBase<double> {
     // whatever
};


int main() {

    testDerived B;

    // Compiler doesn't recognize base class insert
    // How do you do this?
    B.insert(1.0);
}
```

Comment: After editing your question, you yourself gave the answer, which is not suitable. I have reverted to your original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need `public` inheritance (default is `private` for `class`):

```
class testDerived : public testBase<double> {
```

Answer (score 2):

A class has a default access level of 'private'. You basically inherited 'testBase' using private inheritance so that testBase's public interface is not part of testDerived's. Simple solution:

```
class testDerived: public testBase<double> {...};
```

I do wish C++ applied public inheritance by default though since that's generally a much more common case. Then again, we could just all use structs instead. :-D